# Pass a function from one page to another (Not as parent and child)

Tags: reactjs

I have function

```
const confirmedAddress = () => {
   
     console.log("first page")
   
  };
```

in  firstPage.jsx so i have pass this to secondPage.jsx like

```
secondPage(
   
    confirmedAddress
  
  );
```

Then in second page

```
const secondPage=(confirmedAddress)=>
{
confirmedAddress();
}
```

but got an error `confirmedAddress is not a function`.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

1)`FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent` are single file in two places,you can define `confirmedAddress` func and export in `FirstComponent`,so you can import it in anywhere you want.

notice,Don't define it inside, define it outside

```
const confirmedAddress = () => {}

export confirmedAddress

function FirstComponent () {
 return ()
}

export default FirstComponent
```

2)The most force way:mount `confirmedAddress` func on `window` scope,you can use `window.confirmedAddress` anywhere.